# is there any way to run Origami demo on iPhone?

Tags: quartz-composer, origami

Origami is a great prototype tool to make a demo app. The problem is that the demo can only run on Mac OS. Is there any way to run Origami demo on iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

They have launched the iOS Origami App with the new Origami 2.0 for Mac. So now you can test in real time on your iPhone.

[Origami Live for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id942636206)

Comment: Any thoughts @NOrder ?

Answer (score 0):

Quartz Compositions do not run on iOS.